# Filter RelativeLayout out of EditTexts

Tags: java, android

My app crashes when running because there is a RelativeLayout in my XML layout and the loop is searching for EditTexts, how can I filter or skip other objects then EditTexts?

```
private void addData(List<List<ListData>> fields, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    List<ListData> data;

    if (viewGroup != null) {
        data = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        for (int i = 1; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            String str = ((EditText) viewGroup
                    .getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();
            data.add(new ListData(((EditText) viewGroup.getChildAt(i))
                    .getHint().toString(), str));
        }
        if (data != null) {
            fields.add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, I tried everything and searched the web for hours but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
please check with this and let me know if any problem

    private void addData(List<List<ListData>> fields, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        List<ListData> data;

        if (viewGroup != null) {
            data = new ArrayList<ListData>();
            for (int i = 1; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if(viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText)
               {
                                String str = ((EditText) viewGroup
                        .getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();
                data.add(new ListData(((EditText) viewGroup.getChildAt(i))
                        .getHint().toString(), str));
            }

               }
if (data != null) {
                fields.add(data);
            }

        }
    }
```